# Google Translate API - Error code 500 Backend Error

Tags: python, google-translate, google-api-python-client

I'm submitting various queries to Google Translate API via Google API's Python module. Occasionally I receive the error message below:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey='my_key')
translation = service.translations().list(
                    source='zh',
                    target='en',
                    q=text_for_translation).execute()
```

`HttpError: HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=%E7%B7%9A&source=zh&alt=json&target=en&key=my_key returned "Backend Error">`

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid it? I can't find any info on this particular problem.

I seem to get the error randomly, as nearly all of the queries I submit for translation return without any problems. Also, if I re-submit the exact same query it will return successfully.

Answer (score 2):

From google API FAQ page:

> This could happen if you submit text without the source language
>   specified. If Google cannot determine the source language given the
>   text (usually because the text is too short), we will return a 500.
>   This situation can be fixed by specifying the source language
>   explicitly.

For more and other information [Google translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq)

Comment: I have `...source='zh'` in the API call. Maybe there is something else I need to do?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a specific reason due to google I think that you should try to take the failed request and play with it until you get the reason for the failure.